# How to see the code behind an element of the GUI in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

So I recently switched to IntelliJ IDEA from Eclipse for personal reasons, and when I create a GUI and put a button somewhere in on the form, all I see is `private static Button button` in the code (`Main.java`). How can I see the properties of this to customize it easily? Here's a picture of the GUI editor:

[GUI Editor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRY6e.png)

And here's the code I have for that:

```
public class Window {
    private JButton button1;
    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
        frame.setContentPane(new Window().panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And it works out just fine, but, like I mentioned, I have no way of seeing the code of the panel or button. Any way to do this?

Comment: *"[switched IDE] for personal reasons"* You're doing it wrong. Choice of IDE should be a cool, dispassionate assessment of the strengths & weaknesses of each tool, for the particular language or task at hand. As an aside, it seems IntelliJ offers a [GUI designer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gui-designer-basics.html). Are you using that?

Comment: What’s wrong with the java docs?

Comment: Does [this forum post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206757989-GUI-Designer-Where-I-will-find-the-generated-code-) answer your question?

Comment: @CrazyCoder That got it, thanks!